# Is it possible to use jquery to add numbers taken from mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hey guys quick question. I have a div that gets assigned a number to its id that is taken from the database on page load. I am trying to use jquery to add 1 to that number but for example if the number was 70 to begin with it just becomes 701. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
echo "<div class=\"total\" id=\"$total\">$total</div>";

var total=$(".total").attr("id");

var newtotal=total+1;
$('.total').html(newtotal);
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, I do wanna point out your mixed use of PHP and javascript without the necessary divisions (ie:  <script>).  Just in case the above wasn't a summary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   var newtotal=parseInt(total)+1;
```

Use parseInt to convert the String into an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `parseInt()`

```
echo "<div class=\"total\" id=\"$total\">$total</div>";

var total = parseInt($(".total").attr("id"));

var newtotal=total+1;
$('.total').html(newtotal);
```